# TThread::Synchronize() > when reading Form component properties?

Tags: multithreading, c++builder

My Environment:

- C++ Builder XE4
- using VCL component

I have a question about TThread:Synchronize().

Usually, I use Synchronize() when I **update** Form component (e.g. Text->Caption) from the TThread routine().

```
__fastcall TThreadSample::Execute()
{
    Synchronize(&updateFormText);
}
```

where the updateFormText() is a function to update Form Text->Caption.

On the other hand, when I **read** caption from the Form text, I used followings without Synchronize().

```
__fastcall TThreadSample::DoRead()
{
    String acap = CFormXXX::GetTextCaption();
}

void __fastcall CFormXXX::GetTextCaption()
{
    return FormXXX->TextXXX->Text;
}
```

**Question:** Do I have to use Synchronize() also when I **read** Form component properties from a TThread routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**.

Properties are in fact syntactic sugar for function calls. Reading one also means a function is called (*well, most of the time*<sup>[1]</sup>).

In other words, if, in your code, you do:

```
x = MyVCLObj->SomeProperty;
```

the C++Builder compiler in fact generates a call to the (usually private) getter function for the property:

```
x = MyVCLObj->GetSomeProperty();
```

That runs in the context of the main thread, so it must be accessed using `Synchronize()`.

---

[1]  *I know that this is not true for all properties, and you may well be accessing the member field (e.g. `FSomeProperty`) directly, but do you really want to check the docs each time? And this may change in a future version of the class too. So you should generally treat a property access like a function call.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was also introduced following SO QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554875/when-do-i-need-synchronize-in-tthread, which means Synchronous() is needed.

Comment: I will also consider the property access instead of function call, depending on my purpose.